# Difference between char *const *p and char ** const p

Tags: c, pointers

It was asked in an interview . 
As like the idea of reading right to left i can interpret

```
char *const *p declares p as pointer to constant pointer of character.
```

while

```
char * *const p declares p as a constant pointer to character pointer.
```

but since i didn't get the exact meaning of these so please verify it.

Comment: Try to compile p[0] = 0 in both cases

Comment: @Daniel: But both are a pointer to a pointer. The difference is in the placement of `const`.

Comment: Actually, you understood it well. The definitions you gave are the exact translation in common english of jxh's answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char * const *p` means the character pointer that `p` points to cannot be changed.

```
char arr[] = "";
char *ptr = arr;
char * const *p = &ptr;
**p = '\0';             // ok
*p = 0;                 // error
p = 0;                  // ok
```

`char ** const p` means that `p` cannot be changed.

```
char arr[] = "";
char *ptr = arr;
char ** const p = &ptr;
**p = '\0';             // ok
p = 0;                  // error
*p = 0;                 // ok, ptr is now NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

I used to hit my head on the screen when declaring complex pointers in C until I discovered [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) :)

```
char *const *p  // -> declare p as pointer to const pointer to char
char * *const p // -> declare p as const pointer to pointer to char
```

You can also install it.

Cheers!

Comment: You're welcome :) you can also use it to get the C declaration from plain English description, I had a lot of fun building VERY complex variable declarations with it just to annoy a coworker :p

Answer (score 0):

I tested this using the following code:

```
main()
{
  char *const *p;
  char **const q;

  **p = 'a';
  *p = *q;
  p = q;

  **q = 'a';
  *q = *p;
  q = p;
}
```

GCC yelled at me for lines 7 and 12, i.e. `*p = *q` and `q = p`. So it would seem you're right. `*p` is constant, and `q` is constant.

(Yes I know my program has undefined behavior since I dereference uninitialized pointers. That's hardly the *point*, hhhehehe.)